# What does "cotton on" mean?

Tags: meaning, etymology

I was reading a book, and found the the phrase

> cotton on

as in

> "Aha!" he said, when he cottoned on.

At first I assumed this was a misspelling, and it should have been "as he catched on".

But then I find this [daily mail](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/debate/article-2304740/George-Osborne-links-Mick-Philpott-welfare-reform-What-took-long-cotton-on.html) article titled "What took you so long to cotton on, George?"

So now I'm wondering, what does "cotton on" mean?

Comment: to cotton on: to perceive the meaning, understand.http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cotton+on

Comment: *Catched on* would not be correct; it should be *caught on*.

Comment: The earliest instances of "cotton on" (from the 1800s) that I've been able to find appear as part of the longer phrase "cotton on to" and have the same meaning as "cotton to"—namely, "take a liking to." It would be interesting to investigate the circumstances under which the "understand" meaning emerged from the earlier "take a liking to" meaning. The Online Etymology Dictionary's entry for [_cotton_](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=cotton) dates _cotton_ as a verb to the 1560s, "perhaps from Welsh _cytuno_ 'consent, agree.'"

Answer (score 1):

[**Cotton on**](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/cotton%20on): **Understand**, usually ***after some initial difficulty***.

- She didn't know what her classmates were plotting but finally *cottoned on/caught on/got it.*

Examples:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It means the same as "to catch on" or "to understand."

Answer (score -1):

when you interpret or look on something in particular way.
simply,to perceive the meaning.